# How to design when using Node.js for a gaming pairing

Tags: sockets, node.js

I'm using node.js for gaming pairing(for example, several client connect the servers. They are connected to each other if there are more than one players; or they will be kicked for 30sec).

Currently, I'm using socket for connection (and this can detect lost connection unexpected). But I cannot figure out a elegant way for pairing:

```
var net = require('net');
var _clients = new Array();

net.createServer(function(_socket) {
  _socket.on('data', function(_data) {
    //Parse client data
    _clients.push(_socket);
    setTimeout(function(){
      _socket.write('kicked\n');
    },30*1000);
  _socket.on('close', function(data) {
    //Delete _socket from _clients
  }
}).listen(6969, '127.0.0.1');

setInterval(function(){
  var pair = new Array();
  while(_clients.length>2)
  {
    var _s1 = _clients.pop(), _s2 = _clients.pop();
    // Pair _s1 & _s2
  }
},2*1000);
```

The current code works, but it is really bad designed :(

(1)SetInterval is used, rather than asynchronous call. (2)Maintaining an array like _clients is inconvenient, since I have to deal with "kicked"/lost connection/pair or other situations.

PS. Currently I'm pairing clients by time order, but maybe random pair or other condition is needed to avoid always pairing the same people when the online players are not so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use something like the following?

**Without Connection Pool**

```
var net = require('net')
, pendingPair = null;

net.createServer(function(_socket) {
  _socket.on('data', function(_data) {
    //Parse client data
    if(!pendingPair) {
      pendingPair = _socket;
    } else {
      //  Now you have a pair!
      var p1 = pendingPair
        , p2 = _socket;

      pendingPair = null;
    }
}).listen(6969, '127.0.0.1');
```

You get automatic pairs as soon as connections are made. You will still need to track those sockets somewhere for kicking clients, and dropped connections, but you should be able to get rid of the setIntervals.

**With Connection Pool**

```
var net = require('net')
  , _ = require('underscore')._
  , clients = {}
  , games = {};

function setKickTimer(socket) {
    socket.kickTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        socket.write('kicked\n');
    }, 30 * 1000);
}

net.createServer(function(socket) {
    socket.id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
    setKickTimer(socket);
    clients[socket.id] = socket;

    socket.on('data', function(data) {
        socket.data = parseData(data);
    }

    socket.on('close', function(data) {
        var opponent = _.find(clients, function(client) { return client.opponentId === socket.id; });
        //  The opponent is no longer part of a pair.
        if(opponent) {
            delete opponent.opponentId;
            setKickTimer(opponent);
        }

        delete clients[socket.id];
    }

}).listen(6969, '127.0.0.1');

setInterval(function(){
    //  Get the client ids of clients who are not matched, and randomize the order
    var unmatchedClientIds = _.shuffle(_.keys(_.filter(clients, function(client) { return !client.opponentId; })));
    while(unmatchedClientIds > 2) {
        var c1 = unmatchedClientIds.pop(),
          , c2 = unmatchedClientIds.pop();

        clearTimeout(clients[c1].kickTimer);
        clearTimeout(clients[c2].kickTimer);
        clients[c1].opponentId = c2;
        clients[c2].opponentId = c1;
    }
},2*1000);
```

This isn't a complete working solution, but it should give you an idea of how to manage dropped connections and kicking users from the queue. Notice I'm using [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) to make the operations on the collections much easier.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This really helps for removing intervals, but it doesn't work if I want to keep a connection pool and pair them conditionally (just not pair the nearest two)

Comment: You can do one or the other. If you want a connection pool and pairs that are more random then connection order, you'll likely have to do something with intervals. There isn't necessarily anything wrong with that.